# How can I activate bluetooth at startup

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I use a bluetooth mouse and I want it to automatically connect when I switch on the computer. Under Windows this is no problem!!
But when I start Ubuntu, bluetooth is deactivated. I have to use the touchpad (blaaaeh) to navigate to the bluetooth symbol and activate it. Then I have to activate the mouse. That doesn't work at once: I have to go to the bluetooth settings upon which the mouse becomes active.
I've seen a lot of posts where people want to *de*activate bluetooth at startup. It looks like that has become the default, but I want the exact opposite.
I'm new to Ubuntu and currently not convinced it's better than Windows, so I hope somebody out there can help!

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? What is the BT device?

Comment: What is your system's BT manfuacturer and model?

Comment: The BT device is a HP Bluetooth Laser Mobile Mouse. I'm using a HP Mini 210-1000 which has a built in bluetooth connector.

Comment: The Ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS